# Makefile combining fltk and C++ files

Tags: c++, makefile, fltk

I'm trying to make a C++ program with added FLTK library. Separately, files compile. But - I don't know how to combine them into one working file. I think it may be something to do with makefile:

```
COMP=g++
COMP_FLAGS=$(-Wall -g -std=c++11)
FL_COMP_FLAGS=$(shell fltk-config --cxxflags)
FL_LINK_FLAGS=$( fltk-config --ldflags)


program: main.o GraphicsLib.o ChaosSpaceMarine.o SpaceMarine.o Tau.o
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) GraphicsLib.o ChaosSpaceMarine.o SpaceMarine.o Tau.o -o program
main.o: main.cc GraphicsLib.o ChaosSpaceMarine.o SpaceMarine.o Tau.o
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) $(FL_LING_FLAGS)  main.cc GraphicsLib.o ChaosSpaceMarine.o SpaceMarine.o Tau.o -o main.o
GraphicsLib.o: GraphicsLib.cc GraphicsLib.h
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) $(FL_COMP_FLAGS) -c GraphicsLib.cc
ChaosSpaceMarine.o: ChaosSpaceMarine.cc ChaosSpaceMarine.h Marine.o
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS)  ChaosSpaceMarine.cc Marine.o -o ChaosSpaceMarine.o
SpaceMarine.o: SpaceMarine.cc SpaceMarine.h Marine.o
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) SpaceMarine.cc Marine.o -o SpaceMarine.o
Tau.o: Tau.cc Tau.h Marine.cc
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) Tau.cc Marine.o -o Tau.o
Marine.o: Statystyki.o Bron.o Pancerz.o
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) Marine.cc Bron.o Pancerz.o Statystyki.o -o Marine.o
Statystyki.o: Statystyki.cc Statystyki.h
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) -c Statystyki.cc -o Statystyki.o
Pancerz.o: Pancerz.cc Pancerz.h Item.o
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) -c Pancerz.cc -o Pancerz.o
Bron.o: Bron.cc Bron.h Item.o
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) -c Bron.cc -o Bron.o
Item.o: Item.cc Item.h
    $(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) -c Item.cc -o Item.o

clean: 
    rm -rf Item.o Bron.o Pancerz.o Statystyki.o Marine.o Tau.o SpaceMarine.o ChaosSpaceMarine.o GraphicsLib.o
```

So:
Item.o is base class for Bron(weapon) and Pancerz(armor). And with Statystyki (statistics) are part of Marine class, which is base for specific ChaosSpaceMarine, SpaceMarine and Tau.
GraphicsLib contain several FL/Fl_.... headers, so I can make my own graphic objects.

any question and suggestions are welcome here!

EDIT:

Thanks to Lmis and my friend I corrected my makefile, which I put above if anyone have similar problem.

So now I have only one strange error:

```
g++  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -c GraphicsLib.cc
g++  -c Statystyki.cc -o Statystyki.o
g++  -c Item.cc -o Item.o
g++  -c Bron.cc -o Bron.o
g++  -c Pancerz.cc -o Pancerz.o
g++  Marine.cc Bron.o Pancerz.o Statystyki.o -o Marine.o
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Marine.o] Error 1
```

I understand that it says that there is undefined reference to main, but nowhere in this file is such reference, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that:

```
$(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) -o main.o GraphicsLib.o ChaosSpaceMarine.o SpaceMarine.o Tau.o
```

should be

```
$(COMP) $(COMP_FLAGS) -o NameOfYourProgram main.o GraphicsLib.o ChaosSpaceMarine.o SpaceMarine.o Tau.o
```

The `-o` flag tells the compiler what name you want to give the file it produces. What you said in your Makefile was that you want the compiler to compile program called `main.o` using the objects `GraphicsLib.o` and so on.

Since you say

> Separately, files compile.

I assume that all the `.o`-files are compiled just fine and then this answer should fix your problem.